# Plone 4 site is up, but it’s not responding

Tags: plone

I have a Plone 4 site at http://tinakellyrussell.com/ However, when you go to the site, it stalls for a while and then times out. (This even happens when connecting via IP address, so it’s not a DNS issue.) It’s hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance, and if I connect via SSH and use “plonectl status” the result is:

```
instance: program running; pid=788
```

Restarting Plone (or the EC2 instance itself) doesn’t seem to help. It’s been running fine for years, I didn’t make any changes or updates when it started failing. I don’t know what the problem is :(

Comment: Check the instance logs, though usually, if you have an infinite loop somewhere, it will most often terminate when the stack overflows, which at least gives you the beloved "We're sorry, there seems to be an error" page. It might be a proxypass setup incorrectly, because even `/manage` hangs and that wouldn't be affected by Plone theme problems.

Comment: Are you connecting on http at all? If not, have you set up reverse proxying to connect Plone to port 80? If you're running on 8080, have you opened the machine and/or Amazon firewalls for that port?